# Dragging web parts doesn't work on sharepoint 2013 with chrome 51?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, chrome

I am using chrome browser version 51, but when I try to drag web parts around, they don't seem to move. I fixed this issue for IE11, by putting the metatag to IE=10. But it doesn't seem to work on chrome. Does the doctype also affect it? I am using the html5 doctype too.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is so;

1. Open the page in edit mode Edit the webpart which you want to move
   On the webpart properties section (which is on the top right of the
   page)
2. Expand "Layout" section On Layout section, there is two option
   First one Zone selection.
3. If you want to move the webpart to the
   different zone, select the desired zone The second one is Zone
   Index.
4. Use this if you want to change the order of webpart

. For example you have two or more webpart in one zone. So you could
change the webpart order

[image]